# WebDriver executeAsyncScript vs executeScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, webdriver

What is the difference between  executeAsyncScript and executeScript?  How can i use event such as window.onload? I tried something like this

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript("window.onload = function() {alert('Hello')}");
```

But of course it did not work...
So if anyone knows how it works please write an example

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28057338/understanding-execute-async-script-in-selenium

Comment: Look at http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/ CTRL+F and look for "JavaScriptExecutor" and click on that.

Answer (score 37):

(Keeping it *simple*, and *correct*.)

The relevant difference between `execteScript` and `executeAsyncScript` is this:

The function invoked with `executeAsyncScript` takes a 'done callback' as the last argument, which *must* be called to signal that the script is done executing.

This allows it to be used with code that only 'finishes' when a callback is used - eg. setTimeout or asynchronous XHR. If the 'done callback' is not called within the timeout limits the returned promise will be rejected.

Per the [webdriver.WebDriver.executeAsyncScript](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeAsyncScript) documentation:

> Unlike executing synchronous JavaScript with #executeScript, scripts executed with [#executeAsyncScript] *must explicitly signal they are finished by invoking the provided callback*. This callback will always be injected into the executed function as the last argument..

That is, ***both functions block the WebDriver control flow*** until they complete - either running off the end of the code for `executeScript` or when calling the 'done callback' with `executeAsyncScript`: "async" in the name signifies the signal mechanism used and does not mean/imply that the JavaScript code is actually executed asynchronously with respect to the WebDriver.

Answer (score 26):

I use `executeScript`. Example provided:

```
String cssSelector="...blablabla...";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("document.getElementById(\'"+cssSelector +"\').click();");
js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Concerning details on alerts there is known issue. you can get details [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2760)

In accordance with documentation difference is:

> **executeScript**
>
> ```
> public java.lang.Object executeScript(java.lang.String script,
>                              java.lang.Object... args)
> ```
>
> Description copied from interface: JavascriptExecutor
>   *Executes JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window. The script fragment provided will be executed as the body of
>   an anonymous function. Within the script, use document to refer to the
>   current document. Note that local variables will not be available once
>   the script has finished executing, though global variables will
>   persist. If the script has a return value (i.e. if the script contains
>   a return statement), then the following steps will be taken:*
>
> - For an HTML element, this method returns a WebElement
> - For a decimal, a Double is returned
> - For a non-decimal number, a Long is returned
> - For a boolean, a Boolean is returned
> - For all other cases, a String is returned.
> - For an array, return a List with each object following the    rules above. We support nested lists.
> - Unless the value is null or there is no return value, in which null    is returned
>
> Arguments must be a number, a boolean, a String, WebElement, or a List
>   of any combination of the above. An exception will be thrown if the
>   arguments do not meet these criteria. The arguments will be made
>   available to the JavaScript via the "arguments" magic variable, as if
>   the function were called via "Function.apply"
>
> Specified by: executeScript in interface JavascriptExecutor
>   Parameters: script - The JavaScript to execute args - The arguments to
>   the script. May be empty Returns: One of Boolean, Long, String, List
>   or WebElement. Or null.
>
> **executeAsyncScript**
>
> ```
> public java.lang.Object executeAsyncScript(java.lang.String script,
>                                   java.lang.Object... args)
> ```
>
> Description copied from interface: JavascriptExecutor
>   *Execute an asynchronous piece of JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window. Unlike executing synchronous
>   JavaScript, scripts executed with this method must explicitly signal
>   they are finished by invoking the provided callback. This callback is
>   always injected into the executed function as the last argument.* The
>   first argument passed to the callback function will be used as the
>   script's result. This value will be handled in the same way as the
>   synchronous case.
>
> **Example #1: Performing a sleep in the browser under test.**
>
> ```
>  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
>    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(
>        "window.setTimeout(arguments[arguments.length - 1], 500);");
>    System.out.println(
>        "Elapsed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
> ```
>
> **Example #2: Synchronizing a test with an AJAX application:**
>
> ```
>  WebElement composeButton = driver.findElement(By.id("compose-button"));
>    composeButton.click();
>    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(
>        "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
>        "mailClient.getComposeWindowWidget().onload(callback);");
>    driver.switchTo().frame("composeWidget");
>    driver.findElement(By.id("to")).sendKeys("bog@example.com");
> ```
>
> **Example #3: Injecting a XMLHttpRequest and waiting for the result:**
>
> ```
>  Object response = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(
>        "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" +
>        "var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
>        "xhr.open('GET', '/resource/data.json', true);" +
>        "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {" +
>        "  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {" +
>        "    callback(xhr.responseText);" +
>        "  }" +
>        "}" +
>        "xhr.send();");
>    JSONObject json = new JSONObject((String) response);
>    assertEquals("cheese", json.getString("food"));
> ```
>
> Script arguments must be a number, a boolean, a String, WebElement,
>   or a List of any combination of the above. An exception will be thrown
>   if the arguments do not meet these criteria. The arguments will be
>   made available to the JavaScript via the "arguments" variable.
>
> Specified by: executeAsyncScript in interface JavascriptExecutor
>   Parameters: script - The JavaScript to execute. args - The arguments
>   to the script. May be empty. Returns: One of Boolean, Long, String,
>   List, WebElement, or null.

Detailed documentation is [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html)

Comment: The "description" above (copied from the interface documentation) AND the documentation linked to are out of date. A list of "objects" will be returned as a List<Map<String,Object>>. Where, each key is a property of the object. I don't know how to get any details of this, but I just got burned after reading this so I thought I'd contribute.

Comment: @eugene.polschikov  Am referring your example 3 and when i execute the line in console am getting 'Uncaught ReferenceError: arguments is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:16'. Am entirely new to JS and your help is appreciated.

Comment: Documentation link is broken.

Answer (score 9):

The main difference between those are that scripts executed with async must explicitly signal they are finished by invoking the provided callback. This callback is always injected into the executed function as the last argument.

Comment: Why does the poor documentation not say that ? Documentation says only: "Executes JavaScript asynchronously in the context of the currently selected frame or window. "

Answer (score 3):

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("alert('Hello');");
```

will show the alert:

> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript() is used when the JS takes time to execute e.g.in a Web Service call.

`window.onload` makes sure the JS is executed when the page is loaded completely.

Answer (score 2):

I used lots of time to undertand this function and finally I got it. follwing code will help a lot:

```
/**
 * executeAsyncScript document mentioned callback is a browser intrinsic function for returning deferred value (e.g 123 in example) from
 * js environment to Java environment
 * 
 */
@Test
public void testAsyncScript() {
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Integer a = 23;
    TestUtil.elapse("first", () -> {
        Object value = getJsExecutor().executeAsyncScript("window.setTimeout(arguments[arguments.length - 1](123), 500);", a);
        // following code should be executed after 500ms timeout
        System.out.println("a is " + a); // a has nothing to do with the documented "callback"
        assertEquals(123, value);
    });

}
```

Comment: this way you're executing the callback straight away when invoking the setTimeout though

Answer (score 0):

This simple Async script listens for element clicked on the DOM and resolve **executeAsyncScript** through callback

```
  var clicked_element = await driver.executeAsyncScript('var callback=arguments[arguments.length - 1]; window.document.addEventListener("click", function(e){ var element = event.srcElement ||event.target; callback(element); });');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following:

```
JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String javascript="window.location='https://google.com';window.onload=alert('hello'); var callback=arguments[arguments.length-1]; callback();";
        js.executeAsyncScript(javascript);
```

As others said executeAsyncScript() uses a signalling mechanism known as callback to signal main function/code that the javascript in executeAsyncScript has been finished. callback is referred as argument[arguments.length-1].