# Pass value from Js to Java on keypress

Tags: javascript, selenium

I need to open an url using Selenium and execute a script. After sometime on 'Escape' keypress I need to pass value back to Java program.

My **Java** program.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("xp_simple.js")));
String str = (String) js.executeScript(content);
System.out.println("Returned from js : " + str);
```

My passed **javascript** string.

```
var pageName='value from webpage';
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.key === 'Escape') {
    console.log("Escape is pressed");
    return getSG()
     }
} );
function getSG() {
        return pageName;
};
```

**Issue** --> Control doesn't stay until Escape key is pressed. It immediately returns back to java program with str value as null.

Comment: Not going to happen with executeScript. You probably want to look into `executeAsyncScript`

Comment: Can you suggest if I could create endless loop in js code which would break when Escape key is pressed, and thus final value gets back to java code

Comment: I am guessing you did not look up the documentation for executeAsyncScript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452822/webdriver-executeasyncscript-vs-executescript

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked.

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("xpo_simple.js")));
String str = (String) js.executeAsyncScript(content);
```

JavaScript code

```
var pageName='value from webpage';
var callback=arguments[arguments.length - 1];

window.addEventListener('keydown', function (zEvent) {
    if (zEvent.key === 'Escape') {
    console.log("Escape is pressed");
        callback(getSG());
     }
} );
function getSG() {
        return pageName;
};
```